# C# Deserialize list in JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Suppose I have JSON like this, how can I model my class for deserialization?

I have no problems to model class for standard attribute like "dummy" or normal arrays, but in this case, my "links" array is a list of items with different name ("addons", "conditions", "conversion", etc.).

```
"dummy": "1",
 "links": {
            "addons": {
                "href": "/16071d9f-efec-4282-a42e-a495eea76ae0/offers/031C9E47-4802-4248-838E-778FB1D2CC05/addons",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            "conditions": {
                "href": "/16071d9f-efec-4282-a42e-a495eea76ae0/offers/031C9E47-4802-4248-838E-778FB1D2CC05/conditions",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            "conversions": {
                "href": "/16071d9f-efec-4282-a42e-a495eea76ae0/offers/031C9E47-4802-4248-838E-778FB1D2CC05/conversions",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            "list_prices": {
                "href": "/16071d9f-efec-4282-a42e-a495eea76ae0/offers/031C9E47-4802-4248-838E-778FB1D2CC05/list-prices",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            "mutual_exclusion": {
                "href": "/16071d9f-efec-4282-a42e-a495eea76ae0/offers/031C9E47-4802-4248-838E-778FB1D2CC05/mutually-exclusive-offers",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            "prerequisites": {
                "href": "/16071d9f-efec-4282-a42e-a495eea76ae0/offers/031C9E47-4802-4248-838E-778FB1D2CC05/prerequisites",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            "product": {
                "href": "/16071d9f-efec-4282-a42e-a495eea76ae0/products/f245ecc8-75af-4f8e-b61f-27d8114de5f3",
                "method": "GET"
            }
        },
```

Comment: Have you seen [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)?

Comment: You could model links as Dictionary<string, LinkInfo>, where string is "addons", "conditions", "conversion", etc. And LinkInfo have fields href and method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are specifically looking for the set of `LinkTypes` if you will, in your JSON, could you use something like the following, and execute the `Deserialize` on the `RootObject`?

#### Working dotNet Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZWSlK4

*Check out the output on the Console pane on the fiddle page.*

```
public class Link
{
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
}

public class Links
{
    [JsonProperty("addons")]
    public Link Addons { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("conditions")]
    public Link Conditions { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("conversions")]
    public Link Conversions { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("list_prices")]
    public Link ListPrices { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("mutual_exclusion")]
    public Link MutualExclusion { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("prerequisites")]
    public Link Prerequisites { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("product")]
    public Link Product { get; set; }
}


public class RootObject
{
    public string dummy { get; set; }
    public Links links { get; set; }
}
```

and then execute the `Deserializer` like so.

```
var myDummyLinksList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonText);
```

where `jsonText` contains the json string you have listed in your example:

However, if you `List` of `links` objects is dynamic and the number of objects inside varies and you need to capture all of them, <s>then you might have to write a custom **Converter** that inherits from the `JsonConverter` object.</s> then use [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112780/325521) that [@mfarouk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3129298/mfarouk) has posted.

I forked my dotNet Fiddle and implemented his solution and it works like a boss for the dynamic case!

#### Working dotNet Fiddle (dynamic case):  https://dotnetfiddle.net/7bFcNM

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works well. Thank you! I was trying something similar with a List<Link> without success...

Comment: Glad it worked. I was working on writing the dynamic serializer also, if you want to capture these specific Link types into a `List<Link>`. If I get it done, I will update the post too. Also check out the fiddle I created => https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZWSlK4

Answer (score 1):

the `links` attribute could be parsed as key, value dictionary , the class can be like

```
public class JSONClass
{
    public string dummy { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Link> links;

    public class Link
    {
        public string Href { get; set; }
        public string Method { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then de-serialized as

```
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONClass>(JSON);
```

Comment: This works for the dynamic case! I just plugged this code in a FORK of my dotNet Fiddle answer. Check it out here => https://dotnetfiddle.net/7bFcNM